# How do I check a variable inside a python dictionary?

Tags: python, variables, dictionary

I'm working on a project that displays from within the dictionary, and shows options as well. I want some hidden based on your choices as otherwise it would cause redundancy. 
Example Code:

```
scenes = {
   "scene": {
      "description": "The text displayed",
   "paths": [
      { "go_to": "scene2", "phrase": "Proceed to scene 2", scene2seen:True },
      { "go_to": "scene2alt", "phrase": "Only shows if scene2seen is true", if scene2seen:True }
]
}
}
```

Expected output:

```
The text displayed.
 1 Proceed to scene 2
```

The other option would not be displayed until the first one is chosen

The second call for the variable throws syntax errors and I've tried several different methods. Can anyone help?

Comment: Your post is very hard to understand, I guess it would help if you showed expected outputs/worked on improving the readability of the question.

Comment: Yeah sorry, sent via mobile as im on a laptop with no internet access at the moment, and it is VERY hard to type code on it

Answer (score 0):

if you want to create a dictionary dynamically, if I understood your question correctly, it can work like this:

```
{ (your_key if condition else default_key):(value_if_true if condition 
          else value_if_false) for key, value in dict_.items() }
```

or if you can make your question more comprehensible, it would be better.

Comment: I edited to show how the output is displayed using the example

Answer (score 0):

You can access the values for each key like so: `key['value']`

So, if you wanted to get the value for the first path, you'd write `scenes['scene']['paths'][0].

You can also loop through the dict to produce the values as needed:

`for k, v in scenes.items():
    print(k, v)`

Does this answer your question?